# How does one one avoid 404's on changes.list thumbnails when signed in with multiple accounts?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am getting 404's for image thumbnails when I'm signed on multiple accounts and making API calls for changes.list.

The full steps to reproduce the issue are described as below:

1. Be signed in with two accounts, one a personal gmail account, and one a Google apps account, say User_gmail and User_gapps respectively
2. Make API calls to get URLs with to get a list of changes in drive.
3. Load up the thumbnails for images.

Expected behaviour:

Thumbnail images work.

Actual behaviour:

- When I am signed in with User_gmail and User_gapps and I pick
  User_gmail during the authentication flow, I can see thumbails for
  all modified documents.
- When I am signed in only with User_gapps or User_gmail, I can see
  thumbnails correctly.
- However, when signed in as both users, and I pick User_gapps as the user during the authentication flow, I see broken thumbnails.

**Update:** the easiest way to reproduce this is sign into multiple accounts, one personal and one apps account, and use this api. If you authorize the API with your work account, and execute a request, and click on the "thumbnailLink" URLs, you can see 404s.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.changes.list?includeDeleted=false

Comment: How do you retrieve the thumbnails after you get the ist of changes? Can you log the requests, showing one that works correctly and one that fails with 404?

Comment: The thumbnails are used in <img> tags on a web page.

Sure, I can log the requests. Is there an email address I can email you the log?

Comment: You can share the requests here as long as you are removing any sensitive data. This way the whole Drive team can check on it.

Comment: This is an example of the URL for which I get a 404 link when logged into both my personal gmail account and Google apps account, works fine when I am only logged into my apps account:
https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1q9CG288_bG3XQYSy2rDlwCoVjmsotGJL6nHKKrlfZUQ&v=9&s=AMedNnoAAAAAURhPr7AaNyq9Fjj8LNvnIyPqZ8fTZLLY&sz=s220

Comment: It was obtained from:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes?includeDeleted=false&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer [deleted]
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

Comment: It looks like these two questions might also be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445335/whats-the-correct-way-of-using-the-google-drive-thumbnails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330559/thumbnails-url-error-404?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to see a Google Document's thumbnail. After getting the URL of the thumbnail through the Google Drive API this URL can be viewed using either 'Cookie' authorization or OAuth 2.0 Authorization.

You seem to be using the 'Cookie' authorization (i.e. the user is currently signed in the browser). What happens is that the browser will use one of the two accounts by default and unfortunately it might not use the correct account.
In that specific scenario you can append `&authuser=0` or `&authuser=1` to the URL of the thumbnail this will force using an account or the other, one of the two values will work.

The issue is that you don't know which value will work (`1` or `0`) so you would have to test the two URLs programmatically using Javascript to see which one works or fails.

The other way to load a thumbnail is to use OAuth 2 auth. This is more robust. You can do that easily by appending `&access_token=<Your_OAuth_2_access_token>`. Make sure you use the same OAuth access token (formerly known as Bearer token) that you used in your API requests. This way you are sure that the image will load. this will even work if the user has signed-out of his Google Account. You will need access to the actual file's data. So this won't work if you have authorized the `drive.readonly.metadata` scope for instance. YOu need to authorize one of the following scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`

Just beware: access tokens are only valid for 1h.

Comment: Hi Nivco - thanks for the response. I tried both of the above suggestions, and found the following: 1) Adding authuser=0|1 works, as you point out this is not particularly useable given that one is not sure which one to use. 2) I also tried using &access_token=<OAuth2> access token, and this returns a 404. In terms of timing, this is immediately after I got my access token - this was with the Python API. I also have a program with the Javascript API, and I'm not sure where the API client stores the access_token in that case.

Comment: e.g 404 with this valid token:
https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1_ctz0cbnCiZq_u_WDBZA8vS1udOTL3WHxbelgPjg7yA&v=10&s=AMedNnoAAAAAURzXwT0ysFQcVgw-HxU9HD43z9l3X9Bb&sz=s220&access_token=[xxx]
  
{
 "issued_to": "395576897477.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "395576897477.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "[xxx]",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "expires_in": 3537,
 "email": "[xxx]",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "offline"
}

Comment: Okay, after banging my head on this for a while I discovered this.:

You need to do two things to make this work
a) use the access token in the URL as described above.
b) Ensure that the scope that you ask for includes drive.readonly. You can get thumbnails in a listing with drive.readonly.metadata ,but you need drive.readonly scope for actually reading the thumbnails.

Otherwise, you just get a silent 404.

Comment: Hey K.A., correct: I forgot to specify this (updating answer now) the drive.readonly.metadata scope does not give you access to the thumbnails (even if it could be considered as 'metadata'), the thing is that often, the thumbnail does contain actual file's data like the text of a document in the image.

Comment: Hi Nivco, if that is intended behaviour, then I think there are some inconsistencies because I find I can access some thumbnails with drive.readonly.metadata fine, and while some are broken links.

I modified the JS quickstart program to demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/w5Q57/

This program gives me some thumbnails when logged in multi account login, but others are broken links.

Comment: Also can you please ensure that the documentation is updated to note that:
a) scopes differing between getting a listing and using the thumbnails
b) having to use an access_token parameter. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files does not have any of this information.

Comment: Hey K.A. Thanks for your comments. Indeed we need to update the documentation. PS: Some thumbnails do not require authorization, this is an issue on our side, where developers from certain subsystem have chosen to have some kind of authorization tokens self-contained in the Thumbnail URL (often Picasa-like URLs). We are aware of this issue. The general rule should be to always use OAuth when possible (it should work even for these self-auth URLs) with non-metadata only scopes.

Comment: Nivco, we found another problem. The Picasa like URLs break if you use access tokens, while others don't. You mention it should work with those URLs, but in practice it does not. Workaround is to not use the access_token parameter for googleusercontent.com.