# Is there some way to have permalinks to thumbnails in the changes feed?

Tags: google-drive-api

We are looking into trying to look into using the push notifications API to cache some part of the changes feed.

One issue that has come up is that thumbnail links are not cacheable - even if you supply an access token, they expire.

Previously this was a non issue since the lack of push notifications made the application use the changes API, which meant we got back new URLs for thumbnail previews in the new changes results.

Is there a way to cache thumbnails such that we don't have to make calls to the changes API for it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no permalinks available for thumbnails and if there was it'd be a privacy issue, because we dont require access tokens for preview images. I'd not recommend you to cache `thumbnailLink` and `downloadUrl` attributes.

Comment: So I should have clarified: I meant a link which would work if we had access tokens. ( Note that in a previous questions, Nivco had suggested that should access tokens even for thumbnails because otherwise thumbnails don't work for multi account logins - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786367/how-does-one-one-avoid-404s-on-changes-list-thumbnails-when-signed-in-with-mult )