# Google Picker Not Consistenly Loading Preview Images

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I have setup a Google Docs Picker to allow a user to select images either from Google Drive or to upload them.

Once the picker is loaded some of the images' previews in the grid view do not load. This appears to be at random and the error is a 404 (Not Found). The 404 is returned for url of the format
https://googledrive.com/thumb/fileId?access_token=ya....&size=180

Is this something I can resolve in my JavaScript code? See code below.

```
var driveView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES);
driveView.setParent(driveFolderId); //sets the default displayed folder

var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView();
uploadView.setParent(driveFolderId); //set upload parent folder and prevents the user from changing it
uploadView.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg'); //image/bmp,image/gif,image/tiff 
//default file type to png and jpeg

var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
  //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN) //hide navigation
  .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED) // multi select - bug must be enabled to set the upload folder destination
  .addView(driveView) //allows picking files from Google Drive
  .addView(uploadView) //allows uploads
  .setOAuthToken(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token)
  .setCallback(imagePickerCallback)
  .build();

picker.setVisible(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After finding [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786367/how-does-one-one-avoid-404s-on-changes-list-thumbnails-when-signed-in-with-mult), I changed my OAUTH login process to include the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly scope, and it started working. I was only asking for drive.file.